# Divs in line - align to bottom

Tags: layout, html, positioning

I have a problem with div positioning in my form. My page contains a sheet. With div layout as below.

In divs on the left side, there are description of the fields. (they share the same style class)
In divs on the right side, there are the fields. (they share the same style class)

[image]

After validation my page look like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Honestly, I thought how do deal with it, for quite a white, and I simlpy have no idea what to do it. My page is almost ready so I'd like to fix that with possible at low cost.

[edit1]:
My current css look simple, something like this:

```
div_on_left{
   clear: both;
   float: left;
   width: 440px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 8px;
}
div_on_right{
   float: left;
   width: 500px;
   padding-top: 3px;
   padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

[edit2]:
I have just found one solution (posted below), but I don't like it. It will crash if context of divs on the left is too big. That's due to

> position:absolute;

So I'd like to avoid this property.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.row
{
position:relative;
}
.left
{
font-size:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
}
.right
{
font-size:200%;
position:relative;
left:150px;
bottom:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="left">Left_1</div>
<div class="right">Right_1</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="left">Left_2</div>
<div class="right">Right_2</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="left">Left_3</div>
<div class="right">Right_3</div>
</div>
</html>
```

It have to be a common problem. How do you deal width forms with validation that apear over the field boxes?

Comment: I've just added in main post.

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution for your problem but it involves a `table-cell` layout. The layout must have a row and two inner cells aligned to the bottom.
Here is a JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cvbLC/

I'm not aware of which browser support you are needing, but here is more information about this matter: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html